# Message Handler Chain in Spring Boot

Tags: spring-integration

Since Spring Boot recommends Java based configuration, I'm having trouble to convert the following xml based message handler chain config to Java based. Any help is appreciated.

```
<chain input-channel="incomingChannel" output-channel="completeChannel">
<splitter ref="itemSplitter" />
<transformer ref="transformer1" />
<transformer ref="transformer2" />
<aggregator ref="requestProcessor" />
<transformer ref="transformer3" />
<transformer ref="transformer4" />
```

I have tried to use IntegrationFlows to achieve the same as above.

```
 @Bean
public IntegrationFlow incomingFlow(){
    return IntegrationFlows.from(incomingChannel())
            .split("itemSplitter","split")
            .transform("transformer1")
            .transform("transformer2")
            .aggregate()//? need to figure out how to initialize this?
            .transform("transformer3")
            .transform("transformer4")
            .channel(completeChannel())
            .get();
}
```

But I got the following error

```
Failed to transform Message; nested exception is org.springframework.messaging.MessageHandlingException: Expression evaluation failed: locateItemEnrichmentTransformer; nested exception is org.springframework.expression.spel.SpelEvaluationException: EL1008E:(pos 0): Property or field 'transformer1' cannot be found on object of type 'org.springframework.messaging.support.GenericMessage' - maybe not public?
```

Hence I'm not sure if this is the equivalent way in Java code to translate the original chain xml config.

RequestProcessor (aggregator) implementation:

```
    @Component
public class RequestProcessor {

    /** The log. */
    private static Log log = LogFactory.getLog(RequestProcessor.class);


    @Aggregator
    public Message<Requests> aggregate(@Headers Map<String, ?> headers, List<Request> requests) {

        try {
            return MessageBuilder.withPayload(new Requests(service.submit(requests, false, true)))
                    .copyHeaders(headers)
                    .build();
        } catch (ClientException e) {
            log.error(e.toString());
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What are the errors, what have you tried?

Answer (score 1):

There is no obligation to convert the flow from XML to Java - you can use `@ImportResource` to pull in the XML.

It is certainly possible to wire up a `MessageHandlerChain` in java but as you have found, it's easier to use the Java DSL to replace a chain.

The

```
.transform("transformer1")
```

form of `.transform()` (1 `String` parameter) expects an expression, not a bean name.

You can use

```
.transform(transformer1())
```

Where `transformer1()` is your transformer `@Bean`.

**EDIT**

For the aggregator, if you are using Java 8...

```
.aggregate(a -> a.processor(requestProcessor()))
```

...for Java 7 or 6...

```
.aggregate(new Consumer<AggregatorSpec>() {

    public void accept(AggregatorSpec a) {
        a.processor(requestProcessor());
    }
})
```

Comment: But I'm using a custom transformer that cannot implement GenericTransformer interface - which is required by .transform(...)

Comment: It doesn't have to be a `GenericTransformer`; it can be any POJO `@Bean`. `public B transform(Object service)`, as long as it has unambiguous methods; otherwise you can add the method name - this is the same as the XML.

Comment: Thanks Gary, but I don't see transform(Object service) in my IntegrationFlows class.

Comment: BTW, can I use IntegrationFlows.handle(beanName, method)instead of transform, aggregate to handle the message processing?

Comment: `>but I don't see...` - you must be using an old version; it was added in 1.1.0; the current version is 1.1.2. I don't understand your second question; if your chain has an aggregator, you need an aggregator in the DSL equivalent; unless you want to craft your own aggregator. I need to see the implementation of your `requestProcessor` to advise how to wire it in. If it has `@ReleaseStrategy` etc annotations, you can use `.aggregate(requestProcessor(), null)`. If it's a `MessageGroupProcessor`, you can use `.aggregate(requestProcessor())`.

Comment: I upgraded to 1.1.0, the transform piece is working. I've updated my original question to include my aggregator implementation - it simply has a method annotated with @Aggregator

Comment: Please use 1.1.2 - it has some bug fixes over 1.1.0. See my edit.